# Sorted records from LDAP with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap

How to properly get sorted records from LDAP directory. Loading all to memory and then sorting is time consuming because of big amount of data. 
That is why i want (with Spring Boot/SpringLDAP) get already sorted records from LDAP.

I tried to create in @Repository

```
@Repository
public interface XxxRepository extends LdapRepository<Xxx>, Serializable {

   List<Xxx> findAllByOrderByNameAsc(LdapQuery ldapQuery);

}
```

It does not work, NullPointerException.

My @Entity looks like:

```
@Entry(base = "", objectClasses = {"xxx", "xxx"})
public class Xxx implements Serializable {
   @Id
   private Name dn;

   @Attribute(name = "name")
   @DnAttribute(value = "name", index = 0)
   private String name;

   .
   .
   .
}
```

My @Service

```
public void search() {
   String filterConditions = "(&(objectClass=Xxx)";
   filterConditions += "(name=*)";
   LdapQuery query = query().base(BASE_UNIT).filter(filterConditions + ")");
   List<Xxx> xxx= xxxRepository.findAllByOrderByNameAsc(query);
}
```

Comment: FYI this is nothing **at all** to do with the JPA API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer here: [Spring-LDAP LdapTemplateSortedSearchITest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/master/core/src/itest-openldap/java/org/springframework/ldap/control/LdapTemplateSortedSearchITest.java)

```
public void testSearch_SortControl_ConvenienceMethod() {
    SortControlDirContextProcessor requestControl;

    // Prepare for first search
    requestControl = new SortControlDirContextProcessor("cn");
    tested.search(BASE, FILTER_STRING, searchControls, callbackHandler,
            requestControl);
    int resultCode = requestControl.getResultCode();
    boolean sorted = requestControl.isSorted();
    assertThat("Search result should have been sorted: " + resultCode, sorted).isTrue();
    List list = callbackHandler.getList();
    assertSortedList(list);
}
```

It uses **SortControlDirContextProcessor**.